# Unify file sets

Tags: powershell

I am handling a bunch of files with a `ForEach-Object` loop in a powershell script.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "<path>" -Recurse | ForEach-Object { 
    # Do something complicated   
}
```

Unfortunately, I have more than one path in which the files can be, so I would have to write it like this:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "<path>" -Recurse | ForEach-Object { 
    # Do something complicated   
}
Get-ChildItem -Path "<path2>" -Recurse | ForEach-Object { 
    # CAUTION, this block exists 2x in this file!
    # Do the same complicated stuff with the other files
}
```

Is there any way that I could "aggregate" the files in a variable and handle them in just one loop?

Comment: Use both paths for the `-Path` parameter - it supports an array.

Comment: You are great! Why don't you make this a response?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Get-ChildItem` cmdlet's `-Path` parameter supports an array. You can do this:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path <dir1>,<dir2> | ForEach-Object {
  ...
}
```

Or alternatively:

```
<dir1>,<dir2>[,...] | Get-ChildItem | ForEach-Object {
  ...
}
```